# Anyone know if there's a way to report on "lost status" tokens in RSA?

Tags: security, rsa

I want to get a report of all users whose tokens are in "lost status" from RSA. Is this do-able?

Comment: Could you clarify which product you're referring to?  There seems to be some confusion.

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to SecurID tokens, then the RSA Authentication Manager application includes this functionality.  From the **Token** menu, chose "**List tokens...**" and then in the list section choose "All lost tokens".  You can generate the list to screen or to a file.

You can also do this in the web administration interface if you have that set up, by searching on token status.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have any tokens marked as lost to test against, but building out the report this way should work.

From the Security Console, create a new report with the following settings:

Select Template ->  "Users with Tokens"
Select Output Column -> "Users"
Select Input Parameter ->  "Identity Source" = your_ID_source
Select Input Parameter ->  "Lost Token" = "true"

Answer (score 0):

In a Public Key Infrastructure when a key is lost or stolen then it is placed on a black list which everyone has to check to make sure that the certificate is still valid.  [OCSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_Certificate_Status_Protocol) is the protocol that is commonly used to support a [Recovation List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_revocation_list)

This is how you query an OCSP server from the command-line using the OpenSSL tool chain.

```
openssl ocsp -index demoCA/index.txt -rsigner rcert.pem -CA demoCA/cacert.pem
     -issuer demoCA/cacert.pem -serial 1
```